# The virtual path '/theme/miragetheme/user-controls/display-userblog.ascx' maps to another application, which is not allowed. asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I have made subdirectory http://www.mymissioncleanindia.com/blog/. and user control is loaded at runtime. But there is this error

The virtual path '/theme/miragetheme/user-controls/display-userblog.ascx' maps to another application, which is not allowed.

What could be the problem?
Please Help Me.

Comment: Have you found the solution lately. I am facing the same problem and it's eating my head like hell.. please help.

Answer (score 1):

This error means that you've placed the user control outside the root folder where the virtual directory points to. For example if the virtual directory points to `d:\wwwroot\mysite` you cannot have a user control in `d:\wwwroot\someothersite`.

Comment: Thank You very much. There is one site in root folder and one site is in blog folder and all files related are in blog folder. what should i do?

Comment: Site has been uploaded on shared server.

Comment: It's not a permission issue, you can't access controls located on different site. For example you cannot use controls located in the blog site from the root site.